# picketlink-sts ws-trust mustunderstand header

Tags: soap, cxf, jboss7.x, ws-trust, picketlink

Is there a way to configure picketLink-sts to accept soap requests with mustUnderstand headers?

I'm using: https://github.com/picketlink2/picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/ws-trust/picketlink-sts

The request I send is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="urn:picketlink:identity-federation:sts" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.4/cd/ws-trust.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Renew</Action>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:9cfedcee-2ebf-47e0-a24a-45281d785136</MessageID>
      <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://namsb.blr.novell.com:443/nidp/wstrust/sts</To>
      <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
         <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
      </ReplyTo>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
            <wsu:Created>2014-02-10T23:36:42Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-02-10T24:36:42Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">novell</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <wst:RequestSecurityToken Context="context">
         <wst:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</wst:TokenType>
         <wst:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</wst:RequestType>
      </wst:RequestSecurityToken>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The answer is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
         <faultstring>MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The exception:

```
    09:19:56,112 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-5) Interceptor for {urn:picketlink:identity-federation:sts}PicketLinkSTS#{http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws/provider}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood.
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor.checkUltimateReceiverHeaders(MustUnderstandInterceptor.java:150)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor.handleMessage(MustUnderstandInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.MustUnderstandInterceptor.handleMessage(MustUnderstandInterceptor.java:49)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:156)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:145)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
        at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
09:19:56,296 ERROR [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http-/0.0.0.0:8380-5) JBAS015594: Method invocation failed with exception: Security Token Service Exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Security Token Service Exception
    at org.picketlink.common.DefaultPicketLinkLogger.stsWSError(DefaultPicketLinkLogger.java:957)
    at org.picketlink.identity.federation.core.wstrust.PicketLinkSTS.invoke(PicketLinkSTS.java:133) [picketlink-federation-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor432.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:111)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:156)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PL00067: Parsing has failed:CloseSequence
    at org.picketlink.common.DefaultPicketLinkLogger.parserFailed(DefaultPicketLinkLogger.java:470)
    at org.picketlink.identity.federation.core.parsers.wst.WSTrustParser.parse(WSTrustParser.java:63) [picketlink-federation-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.picketlink.common.parsers.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:108)
    at org.picketlink.identity.federation.core.wstrust.PicketLinkSTS.invoke(PicketLinkSTS.java:131) [picketlink-federation-2.7.0.Final.jar:]
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I post it here, it could help someone.

1. You need to define a new SOAPHandler and link it to your webService endpoint.

   This is done by annotating the endpoint with: @HandlerChain(file = "soap-handler.xml")

For example:

```
package org.picketlink.identity.federation.app.sts;
/**
 * imports...
 */

    @WebServiceProvider(serviceName = "PicketLinkSTS", portName = "PicketLinkSTSPort", targetNamespace = "urn:picketlink:identity-federation:sts", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/PicketLinkSTS.wsdl")
    @ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
    @Addressing(enabled = true, required = true)
    @HandlerChain(file = "soap-handler.xml")
    public class PicketLinkSTService extends PicketLinkSTS {
        private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PicketLinkSTService.class);

        @Resource
        public void setWSC(WebServiceContext wctx) {
            log.info("Setting WebServiceContext = " + wctx);
            this.context = wctx;
        }
    }
```

2. Create your handler **SOAPHandlerMustUnderstand.java**

   package org.picketlink.identity.federation.app.sts;
   /**
   *imports...
   */
   public class SOAPHandlerMustUnderstand implements SOAPHandler {
       private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SOAPHandlerMustUnderstand.class);

   ```
   @Override
   public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
       final HashSet<QName> headers = new HashSet<QName>();
       headers.add(getWssSecurityHeader());

       // notify the runtime that this is handled
       return headers;
   }

   private QName getWssSecurityHeader() {
       return new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
               "Security", "wsse");
   }

   @Override
   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void close(MessageContext context) {

   }
   ```

   }

The class defines the headers it understands

Then in the *handleMessage()* method I just return true to continue the handler chain, but this is where you want to check username and password.

3. Create the **soap-handler.xml** file

In the resources folder create folders to match your webservice package.

If your package is: *org.picketlink.identity.federation.app.sts* then you need to create this path: *org/picketlink/identity/federation/app/sts* under resources folder.

Then create a file named: **soap-handler.xml** in the created resources folder.

In the end you have something as: *src/main/resources/org/picketlink/identity/federation/app/sts/soap-handler.xml*

**soap-handler.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains
        xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
        <javaee:handler>
            <javaee:handler-class>org.picketlink.identity.federation.app.sts.SOAPHandlerMustUnderstand
            </javaee:handler-class>
        </javaee:handler>
    </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

Soap-handler.xml defines which class the handler chain have call.